# Why do I seem to lose data using this bash pipe construction?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, c++, process-substitution

I am trying to combine a few programs like so (please ignore any extra includes, this is heavy work-in-progress):

```
pv -q -l -L 1  < input.csv | ./repeat <(nc "host" 1234)
```

Where the source of the repeat program looks as follows:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

inline std::string readline(int fd, const size_t len, const char delim = '\n')
{
    std::string result;
    char c = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
        const int read_result = read(fd, &c, sizeof(c));
        if(read_result != sizeof(c))
            break;
        else
        {
            result += c;
            if(c == delim)
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    constexpr int max_events = 10;

    const int fd_stdin = fileno(stdin);
    if (fd_stdin < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "#Failed to setup standard input" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    /* General poll setup */
    int epoll_fd = epoll_create1(0);
    if(epoll_fd == -1) perror("epoll_create1: ");
    {
        struct epoll_event event;
        event.events = EPOLLIN;
        event.data.fd = fd_stdin;
        const int result = epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd_stdin, &event);
        if(result == -1) std::cerr << "epoll_ctl add for fd " << fd_stdin << " failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            const char * filename = argv[i];
            const int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
            if (fd < 0)
                std::cerr << "#Error opening file " << filename << ": error #" << errno << ": " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            else
            {
                struct epoll_event event;
                event.events = EPOLLIN;
                event.data.fd = fd;
                const int result = epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, fd, &event);
                if(result == -1) std::cerr << "epoll_ctl add for fd " << fd << "(" << filename << ") failed: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
                else std::cerr << "Added fd " << fd << " (" << filename << ") to epoll!" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    struct epoll_event events[max_events];
    while(int event_count = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, max_events, -1))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < event_count; i++)
        {
            const std::string line = readline(events[i].data.fd, 512);                      
            if(line.length() > 0)
                std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I noticed this:

- When I just use the pipe to `./repeat`, everything works as intended.
- When I just use the process substitution, everything works as intended.
- When I encapsulate pv using process substitution, everything works as intended.
- However, when I use the specific construction, I appear to lose data (individual characters) from stdin!

I have tried the following:

- I have tried to disable buffering on the pipe between `pv` and `./repeat` using `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0` on all processes, but that doesn't seem to work.
- I have swapped epoll for poll, doesn't work.
- When I look at the stream between `pv` and `./repeat` with `tee stream.csv`, this looks correct.
- I used `strace` to see what was going on, and I see lots of single-byte reads (as expected) and they also show that data is going missing.

I wonder what is going on? Or what I can do to investigate further?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the `nc` command inside `<(...)` will also read from stdin.

Simpler example:

```
$ nc -l 9999 >/tmp/foo &
[1] 5659

$ echo text | cat <(nc -N localhost 9999) -
[1]+  Done                    nc -l 9999 > /tmp/foo
```

Where did the `text` go? Through the netcat.

```
$ cat /tmp/foo
text
```

Your program and `nc` compete for the same stdin, and `nc` gets some of it.

Comment: You're right! Thanks!
Can you suggest a clean way to disconnect stdin in the ```<(...)```? Is there a nicer way than ```<( 0<&- ...)```?

Comment: `<(... </dev/null)`. don't use `0<&-`: it will cause the first `open(2)` to return `0` as the new fd. If your `nc` supports it, you can also use the `-d` option.

Answer (score 4):

epoll() or poll() returning with E/POLLIN will only tell you that a **single** read() *may* not block.

Not that you will be able to do a lot of one byte read()s up to a newline, as you do.

I say *may* because a read() after epoll() returned with E/POLLIN may still block.

Your code will also try to read past EOF, and completely ignores any read() errors.

Comment: Despite this not being a direct solution to my problem, thanks for making the comment.
I realize that this code has flaws, and EOF detection is present in a less stripped-down version (through use of POLLHUP/POLLNVAL).

I do struggle with finding an unbuffered way to read lines from multiple file descriptors though. My ```repeat``` program is essentially processing NMEA data (line-based and with no length indicators) from multiple sources. 

Since I'm combining data from multiple live sources, I'd like my solution to be unbuffered.
Can you suggest a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: fwiw, doing a system call (read) for each byte is the least efficient way possible. EOF checking can be done by just checking the return value of read, no need for POLLHUP (and POLLNVAL will only be returned when you pass it a bogus fd, not on EOF). But anyways, stay tuned. I have the idea of a `ypee` utility which reads from multiple fds and mix them into another fd, while preserving records (keeping lines intact).

Comment: I noticed that this bash construction should do that, but I don't know how to combine stdin in it:
```{ cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3; } > file```
File will contain what you describe.

However, in my case I'm running everything from tcpserver(3), so I want to include stdin (which contains the client data) as well. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: It depends on what cmd1, cmd2, ... are. If they're nc or cat and your data is line-oriented, the output may be malformed -- you'll get lines consisting of the start of a line printed by cmd1 and the end of a line printed by cmd2.